# Uploading files to Ubuntu server using flask fails with 500 internal server error

Tags: python, flask, os.path

I am running a flask application on a Ubuntu 18.04 system with Apache 2 and uWSGI. When i try to upload files to a directory, it fails with an 500 error code. The script is written in the `__init__.py` and located at: `/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py`. The directory for uploaded files is located at: `/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/uploads`. The script looks like following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, 
send_from_directory, send_file, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/uploads'
#ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #if 'file' not in request.files:
            #flash('No file part')
            #return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        #if file.filename == '':
            #flash('No selected file')
            #return redirect(request.url)
        #if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    #filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''     

"""
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)        

"""                            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It displays the HTML page, but when I click submit after selecting files, it fails. I have tried to run the code both with and without the comments, but it still fails. I think the error occurs at the: `file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))` 
I have also tried several different paths. Could it be something wrong with the configuration of the app? I don't think I have a real settings.py, if that should matter.

Thanks alot for answers

The Flask App Error-log shows this:

```
 ERROR:flask.app:Exception on /test/ [POST], referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
 Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
raise value, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 27, in upload_file, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)), referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2725, in save, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
dst = open(dst, 'wb'), referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/uploads/an_image.jpg', referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/

ERROR:flask.app:Exception on /prov/ [POST], referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
```

Comment: Is there a stacktrace from the flask app itself?

Comment: Looks like the problem is here: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/uploads/an_image.jpg', referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/
referer: http:the.servers.ip.adress/test/".  IIRC, Ubuntu has a www-data user and you're likely running your Flask app as that user.  So `/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/uploads` needs to be writeable by the www-data user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. When you crate a folder inside the Flask App, you have to give it more permissions than the defaults. In my case using WinSCP, i just clicked at every box.

Comment: You don't want to do that.  You just gave *any* user permission to the data, which is generally a security risk.  Please take the time to understand your system and configure things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i just test code in my own it works perfectly make sure you have permission to your upload folder just give write permission to it and the path should be correct there is not any mistake other than it.